# Software for solving geometry problems symbolically

Tags: geometry

I've got Maple and it's excellent when it comes to solving math problems algebraically, but is there a counterpart for geometry problems? Such software would allow me to compose drawings in 2D, specify known lengths and known angles (as symbols, not as numbers), and find lengths and angles that need to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/) is what you're looking for.

Moreover, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_geometry_software) you can find a very detailed comparison of the many geometry software available (free and not). For a comparison of proof related features, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_geometry_software#Proof), but you may be better off with a [proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) (warning: that would require some serious knowledge of logic and programming).

Answer (score 1):

There are many great free software but I suggest what I think is the best: [CaRMetal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CaRMetal).

Answer (score 0):

Another program for geometric theorem proving and discovering is [Geometry Expert](http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/gex/).

Answer (score 0):

Another very good dynamic geometry software(DGS) is Geometer's Sketchpad